# Why my C code gives incorrect output for next palindrome

Tags: c, macos, compilation, execution

I have a C code(find [next smallest palindrome](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PALIN)), which when I run in my local Mac(osx: 10.11.4) and in `ideone`, it gives wrong result for the same input. It does not give wrong for all the inputs but for some of the inputs.

For example here is ran by ideone: http://ideone.com/T4tqak

Here are my results for same input:

input in local:

```
8
97795375756122352572879826552151654387112262
1892388497169516734992356528466
19891859448286167812
47737795782241879811566697829238862994263278849942632926438725
857751275744476297149515661
699
5119783738665448121162642286
4177118624313412937235746451
```

output in local:

```
97795375756122352572877827525322165757359779
1892388497169516159617948832981
19891859444495819891
47737795782241879811566697829233292879666511897814228759773774
857751275744474447572157758
707
5119783738665445668373879115
4177118624313443134268117714
```

Here is the C code for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int all_nine(char* input){
  int result = 1, i;
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); ++i){
    if(input[i] != '9')
      return 0;
  }
  return result;
}

char* increase_one(char* input){
  int i;
  for(i = strlen(input) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if(input[i] < '9'){
      input[i] += 1;
      break;
    }
    else{
      input[i] = '0';
    }
  }
  return input;
}


char* increase_make_palin(char* input){
  int input_len = strlen(input);
  int half_len = input_len%2 ? input_len/2 : input_len/2 - 1;
  int carry = 1, i;
  for(i = half_len; i >= 0; --i) {
    int cur_val = input[i] - '0';
    carry = (cur_val + carry) / 10;
    int new_val = (cur_val + carry) % 10;
    input[i] = input[input_len - 1 - i] = '0' + new_val;
  }
  return input;
}
char* next_palin_for_me(char* input){
    int input_len = strlen(input);
    int half_len = input_len/2  - 1, i;
    for(i = half_len; i >= 0; --i) {
      if(input[i] > input[input_len - 1 - i]){
        input[input_len - 1 - i] = input[i];
      } else {
        return increase_make_palin(input);
      }
    }
    return input;
}

char* next_palin(char* input){
  int input_len = strlen(input);
  if(all_nine(input)){
    return next_palin_for_me(increase_one(input));
  }
  if(input_len == 1){
    input[0] += 1;
    return input;
  }
  input = increase_one(input);
  return next_palin_for_me(input);
}

int main() {
  int n, i;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  char input[1000010];
  for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    scanf("%s", input);
    char* result = next_palin(input);
    printf("%s\n", result);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the *code* in question into the question itself. You've got 13krep, surely you know by now what [MCVE](/help/mcve) stands for!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have added it, However my question was more regarding how to make the compiler same, but nevertheless better to have it here.

Comment: And what is your input? Can it be because of different encoding of your input string? Unicode vs ASCII?

Comment: @MartinPerry input is same, I have copy pasted same input I have given in ideone.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results locally. If the first input matters, then just please provide only the first. This is not yet a MCVE - there is no need to input the count and so forth, it would be enough to just input `97795375756122352572879826552151654387112262` which *should* result in `97795375756122352572888827525322165757359779` (but it doesn't, even on my computer)

Comment: Your "local" results seem incorrect. Have you tried stepping through the execution in your debugger?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala After compiling, when you run, if you just copy paste the 9 lines of input section, it should work. I will add a shorter input in the question. What happens in your case,

Comment: Actually it is not even clear whether you want a **smaller** or the smallest **larger** palindrome?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I want next smallest.

Comment: @Beta Yes, But why I am getting different result in local and ideone and how to make those same.

Comment: @Saurabh **please do understand that to understand why the result is different will be easier if we understand which of the outputs is correct.** I guess `97795375756122352572877827525322165757359779` is correct for `97795375756122352572879826552151654387112262` as it is *smaller*?!

Comment: try rebuild it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `97795375756122352572888827525322165757359779` should be the correct one which I am getting in local, but on ideone I get different which is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have compiled again and tried, same.

Comment: @Saurabh I get 8778 myself, and it is **smaller** palindrome, 8888 is **larger**. You're very much contradicting yourself. Can you ensure once more that you're indeed running the same code locally. I get 8778 with the code pasted here, and with the code from ideone.

Comment: Do you want the smallest palindrome larger than the input, or the largest palindrome smaller than the input? What happens when you try 56122352572879826552151654?

Comment: @Beta  I want  the smallest palindrome larger than the input. output for your provided input from my code in my local  is : `56122352572888827525322165`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char* increase_make_palin(char* input){
    ...
    carry = (cur_val + carry) / 10;
    int new_val = (cur_val + carry) % 10;
    ...
}
```

Note that you change `carry` *before you use it.* Reverse the order of these two lines, and your code will work as you expect.

You can use **8799** as test input, to see how this works. You could have discovered this yourself, by stepping through with a debugger, or reducing your failure case to a simpler one.

As for why it gave the correct answer with the wrong code on ideone (if it actually did; I haven't tried it), I can only guess that perhaps the encoding of the numerals is different there, which would cause trouble with your "- '0'" approach.

### Edit:

```
char* increase_make_palin(char* input){
  int input_len = strlen(input);
  int half_len = input_len%2 ? input_len/2 : input_len/2 - 1;
  int carry = 1, i = half_len;
  while(i > 0){
    if(input_len%2 == 0){
      if(input[i] == input[input_len - 1 - i]) {
        i--;
        continue;
      }
      if(input[i] > input[input_len - 1 - i]) {
        carry = 0;
        break;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
    if(input_len%2){
      if(input[i-1] == input[input_len - i]){
        i--;
        continue;
      }
      if(input[i-1] > input[input_len - i]){
        carry = 0;
        break;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  for(i = half_len; i >= 0; --i) {
    int cur_val = input[i] - '0';
    int new_val = (cur_val + carry) % 10;
    carry = (cur_val + carry) / 10;
    input[i] = input[input_len - 1 - i] = '0' + new_val;
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: You are right, there was one more minor issue, which I just discovered, I have added that as well in your answer.